# Why can't I update the value of this class in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-class

I am following a tensorflow tutorial to learn about time series forecasting:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing

We are predicting the temperature given previous time series data. We create a class to window our data and format it for the model inputs.

```
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
           train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
           label_columns=None):
   # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

   # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
        self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                       enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]
```

We then create datasets from this window.

I am trying to extend the tutorial to consider training the model on different sources of data. Specifically - what if we had training data from multiple locations that we wanted to train the model on? You couldn't just give the windowGenerator class the amalgamated data because the window might end up being half from one location and half from another. So, I have split the data into dataframes for each location. I then create an initial window as per the tutorial:

```
multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=300,
                           label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                           shift=OUT_STEPS,
                           label_columns=['temp'])
multi_window
```

and train the model on this data. So far so good. Once this training is complete I collect the next location's dataframe, update 'train_df', re-create the window, and train the model on the next batch of data:

```
for trainDF in traindfs:
   train_df = mySplitData[trainDF].dropna()
   multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=300,
                            label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                            shift=OUT_STEPS,
                            label_columns=['temp'])
   multi_window
   history = fit_compiled_model(feedback_model, multi_window)
```

The windowGenerator class is re-initialised but with the old 'train_df' - even though the global variable train_df is updated, when the class is re-created it creates it with the original training data from the first location.

I have tried creating a function to update the window, a property.setter, and calling **init** explicitly. I have no idea how to convince the windowGenerator that it is seeing a new train_df - please help!

Comment: What is  `fit_compiled_model` and  `feedback_model` ?  Because, you are defining a new `tran_df` in the loop but you are using the "same" `feedback_model`

Comment: feedback model is a class directly from the tutorial: [link]https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model 
(I have linked again because I can't format correctly within this comment).
fit_compiled_model is a function that contains only my early stopping function and `model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_data=window.val, callbacks=[early_stopping])`. Before the for loop calls `fit_compiled_model` the `multi_window` windowGenerator is re-initialised incorrectly with the old data.

Comment: Yet, I can't see the train_df to be used in your code. You just define your new train_df but you don't use it. You must post a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `train_df` is simply a dataframe. I define the `train_df` and then the windowGenerator class looks at `train_df` when it is initialised in the next line - apart from it sees the old `train_df`. I'm sorry but I don't know how I can post a more minimal working example - this is the code I am using in its most minimal form

Comment: As suggested by @George you define `train_df` but don't use it in WindowGenerator(). In Jupyter notebook it gives false sense that variable is updated but actually it hasn't. You need call `WindowGenerator(..., train_df=train.df)` to make it work.